# SQL count function for specific value

Tags: sql, oracle, count

```sql
SELECT nomDepar, ciudadSede, count(idempleado) as "Numero de Empleados"
from departamentos d, sedes s, empleados
where d.idSede = s.idSede
and s.ciudadSede in ('Madrid')
group by nomdepar, ciudadsede
```

I am trying to count all the employees in the departments located in Madrid. This is what I have so far but I am stuck here. It might be obvious but I only started learning SQL 2 weeks ago and this is stressing me out.

Comment: hi, welcome. You need to add schema, data sample and expected result in text formats as a table or DML/DDL.

Comment: You are missing a join on the empleados  table and field references to table aliases.  You should be using ANSI joins.

Comment: You should never have a comma in your SQL FROM. That syntax has been outdated since the early 1990s. Use proper JOINs. If your book/tutorial/video is teaching the syntax you're using, throw it out and find one that is teaching actual modern SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing, but it should be like here:

```sql
SELECT      d.nomDepar, s.ciudadSede, count(e.idempleado) as "Numero_de_Empleados"
FROM        departamentos d
INNER JOIN  sedes s ON(s.idSede = d.idSede)
INNER JOIN  empleados e ON(e.idSede = d.idSede)  -- just guessing this join condition - you should put your own - there was none in your code
WHERE       s.ciudadSede = 'Madrid'
GROUP BY    d.nomDepar, s.ciudadSede
```

Comment: I will try this once I get home and update the post. Thank you for the reply! :D